# Includes not finding character after space

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple javascript `.includes()` check on a string to see whether or not a name contains a specific letter.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
this.recipients = this.originalRecipients.filter((item) => {
    let test = item.name.includes(val);
    return item.name.includes(val);
});
```

But it would seem that if the name contains a space, `includes()` won't match after the space. I.e. if I have the name, `Landry Farrell` and the letter I am checking for is `f` `includes()` returns false.

You can see that in this screenshot when the debugger was hit, in this case `val` was `f`:
[image: Javascript debugger]

Comment: convert both to lower case or upper case. Difference in case is a very common problem in situations like this one.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks @nickzoum!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Includes method is case sensitive
So you need to lowercase everything when you want to search with case insensitive